# move class between elements with pure JavaScript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript

Can you help me here with this ordinary js code as I want to move the className "active" from item to another item including removing all elements class and keep it with the this.item

```
function moveClass(){

  var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

  for(var i = 0 ; i < item.length ; i++){

    var items = item[i];

    items.onclick=function(){

    items.classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');

    }
  }

}

window.addEventListener('load',moveClass)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each item and remove the `active` class from it.  Then add `active` to `this` (the item being clicked)

```
function moveClass(){
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for(var i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++){    
    items[i].onclick=function(){
      for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        items[j].classList.remove('active');
      }
      this.classList.add('active');
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load',moveClass)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zutqwdf8/

Comment: i see you have to make inner for loop to make all elements remove class.
thanks man it works

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please mark it as such.

Comment: Yes. The way you have it, the `onclick` handler removes the `active` class from the element referenced by `items` (the last `item`) and then adds the `active` class to the clicked item.  The `items` variable, preserved as part of the function closure, points to the last `item` because that that was the last thing assigned to it in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector('.item.active')` to find the current active item, and remove `.active` from it. Afterwards, just assign active to the clicked item ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/rzrescby/)):

```
function moveClass() {

    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        items[i].onclick = function () {
            var prevActive = document.querySelector('.item.active');

            prevActive !== null && prevActive.classList.remove('active');

            this.classList.add('active');
        }
    }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', moveClass);
```

Comment: this is much easier but what is the 
 prevActive !== null && prevActive.classList.remove('active') 
is it like if condition ?

Comment: If there isn't an active item, prevActive is null. If it is null don't try to remove the class from it (it will throw an error).